# Play Store is not loaded, showing a blank screen instead

Tags: google-play-store

I am on an LG G4 running on Android 7.0 Nougat.

Whenever I try opening Google Play Store, I only see a blank screen, even after waiting for more than 10 minutes with the screen on:

[image: blank, grey screen]

I have tried the following:

- Rebooting
- Clearing cache
- Deleting data
- Uninstalling updates
- Doing all the above with reboots between.

Yet nothing works, I still get the blank screen.

Is there a way to fix this without going through a factory reset?

Comment: I found these same issue in my device but after updating google play it stopped.

Comment: @JSLavertu Try uninstalling updates to google play, and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: this is not a *good* solution.

I messed around in the account settings of my phone. For some reason, I could not remove my Google account (to re-add it after), but trying to do so seems to have triggered something in the software that got everything working. I believe it had to do with the syncing not working properly as my Gmail and calendar apps weren't working properly either.

So that could be a possible direction in which to search.

Answer (score 0):

June 2018, just happened to my LG G4 (yes, it's still running).
Deleting cache/data for the Play Store didn't do the job.
Reinstalling the Play Store with APK didn't do the trick either

In the end, I took drastic measures:

1. Cleared the data + cache and uninstalled updates on both Google Play Store and Google Play Services (set them back to the factory installation)
2. Turned off data and used a secure/private WiFi connection instead
3. The Google Play Store app opened! I had to re-enter my Google account info and download all the updates, but it is working again, yeah!